# how to update table by clicking a link in php

Tags: php, mysql, href

I have a project where I create a point system for students. A student may look at the solutions to a question, but if they do, they should lose 2 pts and their profile should also updated with new point score. Is it possible to update a table by clicking on a link? I attempted to do the following:

```
if($points >0)
{
    if(($status== '') || ($newuniq_id!= $uniq_id) || ($newquestion_id!= $quid))
    {   
        $query = "insert into status(uniq_id, user_id, user_name, question_id, status) values('$uniq_id', '$id','$name','$quid','read')";
        mysql_query($query);

        $newpoints = $points - $cut_points;
        $newquery1 = "update $tabl_u set points = '$newpoints' where uniq = '$uniq1'";
        $newquer2 = mysql_query($newquery1);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow...if u dont know answer..just down voted the question.. :(

Comment: Actually I down voted because of the lack of capital letters and punctuation in your question.

Comment: okay....may be, i clearify it as much as i can.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your php script is myscript.php

You can create each link that reference your script with the uniqid of the item you want to update.

```
<a href="myscript.php?update=true&uniqid=<?=$uniqid?>" />
```

Then in your script, you can check for the update GET request:

```
if (isset($_GET['update'])){
  $uniqid= $_GET['uniqid'];
  $newquery= // your update statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check some of the PHP documentation as the mysql_* function set has been depreciated. To solve your problem, I would request back to the same page using the standard "a href" link, which will carry your data in the URL, or using $_POST if you dont want your users to see the data in the URL.

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
```

mysqli_* is available to use.